# Serializing an immutable struct in a SecurityTransparent assembly

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0

I'm starting a new project on .NET 4. All the libraries I'll be creating will have `SecurityTransparentAttribute` applied.

Now I have an immutable struct in one of these assemblies that needs to be serialized. As an immutable object, there won't be setters for any property (like with `System.DateTime`).

If I simply mark the struct as `[Serializable]`, nothing will be serialized, as the properties are readonly. The usual way to deal with this is to implement the `ISerializable` interface and take care of it in `GetObjectData` and the special constructor.

But in this case, my assembly will be security transparent, and `ISerializable.GetObjectData` is `SecurityCritical`, so I can't do it this way.

So, what are my options here? I would really like to have everything `SecurityTransparent` because I won't really need any critical stuff. Except this.

Thanks

Comment: Ive not really played around with the Security attributes so this may be way off, but if you have a look at DateTime the GetObjectData method has the following attributes [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)] Would they help you in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `BinaryFormatter`, it serializes the fields of your struct, not its properties, and it works even if the fields are `readonly`. So if it's appropriate to serialize your struct by simply serializing its fields, you're all set.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that works. But I don't think it's all we need in some cases. In this case I would like to make sure that I could send my struct across the network, in web services, REST services, and so on. I will check how WCF serializes data.

Comment: Ok, it appears that both ´DataContractSerializer´ and ´NetDataContractSerializer´ are capable of serializing such struct. They even respect the ´NonSerialized´. That's enough for me :)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that is the knowledge of how to serialize itself too much behaviour to have in a struct?

You could go down the route of creating a [type converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) for it

Comment: Yes, in general, I would agree with you on keeping the struct simple. But in this case I need to be able to serialize it. I'm doing just like `System.DateTime`(which implements ´ISerializable´)